# Change post permalink dynamically via custom field on save/update

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-fields

I'm wanting to change a WordPress post's permalink (`post_name`) dynamically every time time a post is saved/updated by pulling from a custom field present in the post and replacing the permalink with this value. I have code within `functions.php` which is working, except that it appends `-2` to the permalink. I assume this is because something is occurring twice, the first time resulting in the permalink I want, and the second resulting in WordPress responding to the "duplicate" by adding `-2`.

This is the current code:

```
add_action('save_post', 'change_default_slug');

function change_default_slug($post_id) {

if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
return;

if ( !current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id) ) 
return;

remove_action('save_post', 'change_default_slug');

wp_update_post(array('ID' => $post_id, 'post_name' =>get_post_meta($post_id,'request_number',true)));;

add_action('save_post', 'change_default_slug');
}
```

Comment: If WP finds an existing permalink with the same name, the default behavior is to append -X to it which is what you're seeing. I noticed you're calling the "change_default_slug" action on the same function (change_default_slug) twice. The second time its called is while it's inside the function it would call, that might give you some goofy behavior.

Comment: I cleaned the code up a bit and got it to work with an ACF field. Can you elaborate on what your "request_number" custom field looks like? If it's a simple text field it should work

Comment: Can you try removing the `remove_action` and `add_action` hook inside your function? I have a feeling that when it's added back in it's running everything again.

Comment: @JDev518 `request_number` is in fact just a text field, so I'd be interested to see what code you got to work. @Daniel James removing `remove_action` and `add_action` from within the function doesn't work, and actually causes the backend to never load. I've tried as well removing the second instance of `add_action`, the one within the function and the one outside, with no luck either. Thanks to both for replying.

Comment: Also, asking preemptively: now that I've gone and apparently created a /xxx-2 slug for all my posts, once I have the correct code is there a way to convince WordPress that it is okay to use /xxx and "overwrite" what it considers to be the original offending slug?

Comment: I just added the code to my theme's functions.php file and setup a regular text field in ACF. For posts or pages it seems to update the permalink without any problems. It makes me think it's related to a configuration issue. Having `remove_action` and `add_action` in the function actually prevents an infinite loop that WP can't recover from while executing `wp_insert_post()`, e.g.: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached, aborting!`

Comment: @JDev518 the same code I have above works for you when placed in `functions.php` with an ACF text field with no problems or `-2` duplicates? What exactly could be the "configuration issue"? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a crack at this...

Now, this is assuming that you are using ACF for your custom field...
If not, simply update the code with the WP custom meta functions instead. Oh, don't forget the change the field_5fed2cdbc1fd2 with your ACF field Key

```php
add_filter('save_post', 'change_post_name', 20, 1);
function change_post_name($post_id)
{

  $post_type = get_post_type();
  if ($post_type == "post"){

                
     $acf_title_field = $_POST['acf']['field_5fed2cdbc1fd2']; // get the field data by $_POST

    if (!empty($acf_title_field)) {

        // update the title in database
        $wpdb->update($wpdb->posts, array('post_title' => $acf_title_field, 'post_name' => sanitize_title($acf_title_field)), array('ID' => $post_id));  

    }
  }
}

add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'update_post_name', 50, 2 );
function update_post_name( $data, $postarr ) {
    $post_type = get_post_type();
    if ($post_type == "post"){
        //Check for the  post statuses you want to avoid
        if ( !in_array( $data['post_status'], array( 'draft', 'pending', 'auto-draft' ) ) ) {  

            $acf_title_field = $_POST['acf']['field_5fed2cdbc1fd2']; // get the field data by $_POST
            // $data['post_name'] = sanitize_title( $data['post_title'] );
            $data['post_name'] = sanitize_title( $acf_title_field );

        }
    return $data;
    }
}
```